# Math.random() JS

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

```
var rand = Math.random(1, 3);
alert(rand);
```

Данный код всё время выдаёт примерно такие числа: 0.265656231225, на диапазон вообще не реагирует. Всегда 0. В чём же проблема?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function myrand(c_min,c_max){
  return Math.round(Math.random()*(c_max-c_min)+c_min);
}
```

Родной рэндом выдает число в диапазоне 0..1, так что бесполезно умолять, упрашивать и передавать аргументы